# Google maps api, google places api autocomplete for provinces only?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

According to the google Places doc and Autocomplete I can use the "regions" type to return a collection of results, can i further restrict it to return only provinces say(administrative_area2)?
this is the google docs: 
the (regions) type collection instructs the Places service to return any result matching the following types:
locality
sublocality
postal_code
country
administrative_area1
administrative_area2

Answer (score 0):

The region types you are talking about could be used if you only want to show provinces themselves as the results. But if you want to show addresses in those provinces you unfortunately cannot.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702720/google-map-api-autocomplete-restricted-bias-to-street-address-in-my-town)