# Google places api auto complete doesn't return what I want

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

Check this api url

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=jolibee&location=8.2285156,124.2413198&radius=500&key=API_KEY

I expect this request to return places named "jolibee" in the given location within the given radius .. but the results returns places beyond the given parameters.

Is there anything wrong with the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The location is **bias**, not a filter.  See this answer, for example: [Google map api autocomplete restricted/bias to street address in my town](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702720/google-map-api-autocomplete-restricted-bias-to-street-address-in-my-town).